# datatables search configure

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

У меня есть столбик с номерами телефонов, где они отображаются в отформатированном виде, как: +7 499 879-94-24. Поиск `DataTables` ищет по значению, то-есть с пробелами надо вводить номер.

Как мне сделать, чтобы при вводе в поиск без пробелов, находило номер, например: (+7499..)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите плагин для фильтрации. Этот плагид при поиске удаляет лишные значения

```
jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.phoneNumber = function ( data ) {
    return ! data ?
        '' :
        typeof data === 'string' ?
            data + data.replace(/[ \-]/g, '') :
            data;
};
```

пример таблицы

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
      columnDefs: [
        { type: 'phoneNumber', target: 4 }
      ]
    } );
  } );
```

JS в CDN: [//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.10/filtering/type-based/phoneNumber.js](http:////cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.10/filtering/type-based/phoneNumber.js)

[источник](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/type-based/phoneNumber)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.